# Map single object or multiple objects?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, datamapper

As you can imagine, a search involving the terms (in any combination) "multiple, tables, objects" returns a lot of pages that are not specific to my particular question -- and I'm not entirely sure how to word it, so I will give an example:

Say I have these tables: 'Users', 'Projects', and 'ProjectNotes'. On any given view (working with an MVC pattern) I may want to call up information about one or more projects and display information about their parents users and child notes -- or for the sake of having a more specific scenario, let's say I want to have a view that displays information about a single project along with its child notes and maybe a reference to the parent user's first and last name.

In such a scenario, should I map one object which contains all required data and pass it to the view, or should I map the specific project, use its 'user_id' foreign key to map the appropriate user object, map all of the project's child notes as objects, and send this group of objects to the view?

I thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strikes me as a toss up, either way seems fine. But I'd lean towards the latter: assemble all your per-record data into a single array/object and pass that to the view.

Ultimately, the specifics of what data is easily available to you in the action depends upon your queries, your ORM, the object graph that get produced by the queries/mappers/ORM, etc. But assuming that your joined query produces a Project that has members for Note and User, you could do something like this in your action:

```
$project = $repository->getProject(); // however this is done
$this->view->projectData = array(
   'name' => $project->name,
   'date' => $project->date,
   'user_name' => $project->User->name,
   'user_email' => $project->User->email,
   'note' => $project->Note->content,
);
```

That is, the view doesn't need to know about the object graph; this knowledge resides at the level of controller/action and above. The action unwraps the data from the graph and rewraps it into a simple form (array) for the view to render.

You could even push this down into an intermediate view-model object representing the `$project` - one that accepts the `$project` object/graph in the constructor, but is immutable and read-only. Then pass this view-model object to the view for rendering.

Comment: Thank you for responding; your code-blocked approach seems very similar to what I had envisioned -- a project object with an 'owner' property and a 'notes' property, containing an object and an array of objects, respectively.

I am still tossing around ideas about how the all of the objects which will be contained as properties (user and notes for a project, author for each note) should be instantiated and where.

Comment: I bought the book PoEAA by Martin Fowler and learned/implemented the Lazy Load pattern some time ago. Thank you again for your response. I enjoy your idea about not giving object to the view, although I already use json so it's just as easy to give objects to the view.